# How to connect to socket each tym when a specific ng-view is loaded? and destroy when unload?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I m trying to build an web app with angular socket.io and nodejs. is it possible to connect to server socket each tym when an specific template is loaded on ng-view? i tried it in several way. it works only the first time. i have to refresh the page when i loaded another view and come back to the old one, otherwise it does not works !
thank u in advance !
server side code:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket){
  Events.find().exec(function(err,existing_events){    
      if(err)
      {
          console.log(err);
          socket.emit('err',{message: "events can not be loaded now!"})
      }
      else
      {
        socket.emit('events',{events: existing_events});
      }
    });
}
```

here is client side code:
angular configuration:

```
window.app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        $routeProvider.
        when('/event', {
            templateUrl: '/views/eventsHome.html'            


        }).
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/index.html'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }
]);
```

eventsHome.html:

```
<div ng-controller="eventsCtrl">
  <label style="width:15%;float:left;">Current Events</label>
  <a style="float:left;" href="" id="create" ng-click="create()">Create Event</a>
  <div style="border:none; width:90%; max-height:200px; overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden; clear:both; padding-left:2%; margin-top:5%;">


    <div id='events' ng-repeat="event in events">
            <a href="/event/{{event.name}}" ng-click="leave()">{{event.name}}</a>

    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

eventsCtrl:

```
angular.module('myApp.system').controller('eventsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Global','$location', function ($scope, Global,$location) {
      var socket;
      var sessionId = '';
      var serverBaseUrl = document.domain;
      socket = io.connect(serverBaseUrl);
      $scope.events;
      socket.on('connect', function () {
        sessionId = socket.socket.sessionid;
        console.log('Connected ' + sessionId);
        //socket.emit('newUser', {id: sessionId, name: user_name});
      });
      socket.on('events',function(data){
        //updateEvents(data.events);
        $scope.$apply(function () {
          // body...
          $scope.events=data.events;
        });

      });

 }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do what you want (assuming I'm understanding correctly), is to use the `$route` service to listen for view changes.  The docs for the all of the available `$routeChange` events are found in the [Angular Docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/api/ngRoute.%24route).  Here's an example of how to listen for route changes:

In your `'eventsCtrl'` controller:

```
.controller('eventsCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', ... // and other dependencies
    function($scope, $rootScope, ...){
        ...
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(e, currRoute, prevRoute){
            switch(currRoute){
                // test for which specific routes you want to check for
                // such as connecting to or destroying your various sockets
            }
        });
        ...
    }
]);
```

This will notify the `$rootScope` every time a route changes and tell you which route it was changed to.  Hopefully that does what you wanted it to.